# Subset with loop over an array of strings

Tags: arrays, string, r, loops, subset

I have my code like this:

```
for (i in 1:b) {
carteraR[[i]]=subset(carteraR[[i]],RUN.FONDO=="8026" | RUN.FONDO=="8036" | RUN.FONDO=="8048" | RUN.FONDO=="8057" | RUN.FONDO=="8059" | RUN.FONDO=="8072" | RUN.FONDO=="8094" | 
RUN.FONDO=="8107" | RUN.FONDO=="8110" | RUN.FONDO=="8115" | RUN.FONDO=="8130" | RUN.FONDO=="8230" | RUN.FONDO=="8248" | RUN.FONDO=="8257" | RUN.FONDO=="8319")
}
```

Where `b=length(carteraR)`, and `class(carteraR[[i]])=data.frame`. `RUN.FONDO` is one of the head of these data frames. This code is working fine but I want to save some lines.

What I want is something like:

```
for (i in 1:b) {
for (j in 1:length(A)){
carteraR[[i]]=subset(carteraR[[i]],RUN.FONDO==A[j])
}
}
```

And where `A= "8026" "8036" "8048" "8057" ... "8319"` ....... etc......

What should the code be like ?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
carteraR <- lapply(carteraR, subset, RUN.FONDO %in% A)
```

Just be aware there can be risks with using `subset` in a programmatic way: [Why is `[` better than `subset`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860090/in-r-why-is-better-than-subset). This usage is fine though.